# How to remove continous extensions in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

For example, I want `$(remove_all_extensions foo.bar.buz.x.y.z)` to return `foo`.

`basename` doesn't work because it only remove the last extension so `$(basename foo.bar.buz.x.y.z)` returns `foo.bar.buz.x.y`.

Is there any built-in function I can use in Makefile to achieve the requirement?

Comment: `$(firstword $(subst ., ,foo.bar.buz.x.y.z))`?

Comment: (sorry I forgot to add: if you use GNU make)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob-match` in [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which can cut strings with glob syntax. For your problem the pattern `*.*` is fitting. If a match with the input string results, `glob-match` returns the string portion corresponding to the glob character, which in this case is `*` for the leading portion, then the first `.` and then the rest with all commas for the remaining `*`.

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

FILES := foo.bar.buz.x.y.z frob.ni.ca.te biz.bof zulu.oat.s

$(foreach f,$(FILES),$(info $(call glob-match,$(f),*.*)))
```

Output:

```
 foo . bar.buz.x.y.z
 frob . ni.ca.te
 biz . bof
 zulu . oat.s
```

so you have to `$(firstword )` on the result of that call.